# Is there any way how to use a variable as a name of an added column using SQLite in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to add a column to an already existing table, where the column name would be a current date. I've tried to run all of these below but none of them works. I've also tried to replace '-' in the date (YYYY-MM-DD) with '_' or get rid of them completely...

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

dt = str(datetime.date.today())      # also tried .replace('-', '_') or just .replace('-' ,'')

c.execute('''ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN {} INTEGER'''.format(dt))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Second version would only differ in the execute statement:

```
c.execute('''ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN ? INTEGER''', (dt, ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First version won't work because `dt` "looks" numeric to sqlite, use [] or `` around the {} to indicate it is an identifier.

The second version won't work because column names (and table names) cannot be parametrized.

Date as a column name raises a red flag about data base design.